# ProgressBar is showing when image is already loaded

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I am using universal image loader library to display the images.
my issue is i have a progress bar for image loading, means unless and until image won't load progress bar is displayed,
But progress bar still get displayed when image is loaded .

following is my code

```
    final ImageView imageView = ...
    final ProgressBar spinner = ...

    imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrl, imageView, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
        spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
        spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
        spinner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});
```

i have used the above code, but the problem is my spinner is still displayed when image is already loaded and displayed.

Why is this so?

Comment: please paste your entire code

Comment: Please check if `onLoadingComplete` or `onLoadingFailed` is getting called or not? and check if they are called then something else is not making your loader visible.

Comment: Check visibility of progressbar in xml file

Comment: @himanshu1496  yes onLoadingComplete is getting called, but still its showing.

Comment: so in this case you gotta check whatelse is making your loader visible.

Answer (score 1):

Use like this `show()` when start and `dismiss()` when finished.

```
        ProgressDialog progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progress.setMessage("Downloading image ");
        progress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progress.setIndeterminate(true);
        progress.setProgress(0);

        imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrl, imageView, options, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                progress.show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {
                progress.dismiss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                progress.dismiss();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly dismiss the `Progressbar`. For instance in your code, you could do something like this:

```
@Override
public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
    //dismissing the progressbar dialog
   spinner.dismiss();
}
```

Give it a try and let us know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

**Use dialog as per below**

```
ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(ShowMessage.this);
dialog.setMessage("Loading Image");
dialog.show();
```

**and dismiss dialog after process adds**

```
dialog.dismiss();
```